#  Generate drop down from non-direct-link database table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I got 3 tables in database, FOOD, FOODTYPE and FOODUNIT. FOOD is link with FOODTYPE with foreign key FoodTypeID, while FOODTYPE is in turn link with FOODUNIT with foreign key FoodTypeID as well.
Currently i got my strongly-typed view (FOOD) which display all food data. I got a dropdown for FOODTYPE table like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<HFMS1.Models.FOOD>
<td id="type@(item.FoodID)" class="dropdown">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FOODTYPE.FoodTypeName)
</td>
```

I need to generate another drop down for FOODUNIT, but since this table is not directly link with FOOD table, i got no idea how i going to call it, is it i need to pass ViewBag from controller ? 
Really no idea about this. hope can get some help here. appreciate that.

Comment: Why don't de-capitalize tables' name?

Comment: hi, how does it related to the drop down?

Comment: It's not related to drop down. It's related to your model in general.

Comment: capitalized the table name is just a group decision, any side effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper to use as your model that contains both FOOD and FOODUNIT (unless I'm misunderstanding the question).

So for instance create a class such as the bellow:

```
public class FoodViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<FOOD> Foods { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FOODUNIT> FoodUnits { get; set; }
}
```